# counterxample: Events with bounded minimum probability not having a subsequence with 0 probability

Tags: probability-theory

So,  I'm trying to come up with a counterexample (Or proof if that would be easier that thi thing is false, but it seems like counterexample is the normal way to show something is false...)  Anyhow, the statement is:

Given $\epsilon >0$ and a sequence of events $\{A_n\}$ with the property that for each $n$, $P(A_n)\ge \epsilon $,  it follows that there exists a subsequence $n_k$ tending to infinity such that $P(\bigcap _k A_{n_k})>0$

So,  obviously the events aren't going to be independent, but that wasn't required.   Each event has a certain minimum probability,  so I can only fit $\frac 1 \epsilon $ disjoint such sets, so obviously there's going to have to be infinite overlap.  Somehow I have to massage this overlap so that there's no way to find a subsequence whose intersection has positive probability.  I've played around with various probability densities on $\mathbb R$,  but can't seem to manage it.  Any thoughts/pointers?

Comment: Let $\varepsilon = \frac{1}{2}$, $P(A_n) = \frac{1}{2}$, and $n_k = k$ then $P(\cap_k A_{n_k}) = \prod_{k=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2} = 0$, if the events are independent.

Comment: @genisage Is it possible to have an infinite sequence of independent events with probability $\frac 1 2?$

Comment: sure, take an infinite number of coin flips for example.

Comment: Doh,  my brain's been fried by the theory side to actually see the common sense.   Thanks,  that solves it